# Prevent Unwanted Access to API by normal authorized users in .NET 6

Tags: .net, angular, authorization

I am working on a web service using .NET 6 and Angular. My Angular Web App sends requests to my .NET API. Each endpoint in my controllers that I want to protect has the `[Authorize]` attribute to ensure that the user has to be logged in to access it. Some also specify specific roles when needed. However, at the moment, nothing is present to prevent someone from writing an application to access the API by using their own access token and I'm not yet sure how best to prevent this. I've looked at the User Agent in the request, but that is not consistent or reliable, neither is the referrer or origin. To me this seems like it should be easily answerable but I feel like I am asking the wrong question or making some sort of fundamental error. What is the best practice to lock down an API that is used by a web client to make sure it is only available to that web client. I know that nothing is perfect and there will always be workarounds, but I am trying to do my due diligence and make it at least as difficult as possible.

I have tried to use a middleware and look for an API key, but I would have to somehow filter out those who actually need to use an API key without blocking normal users trying to access the API via the web app.
I have also tried using a filter but I don't want to force web users to have both their normal credentials on top of an API key, as that defeats the purpose of both.